# I Lost My Ethereum Wallet Backup

Tags: wallets, ether, backup

I have setup Ubuntu on my laptop after having Windows 10 on it, and I lost my Ethereum wallet backup file. Now I have returned to Windows 10, is there any way to restore my wallet again without my backup file?

Or any way to recover my `.json` backup file on Windows 10?

Comment: Image your drive ASAP.

Answer (score 1):

There's no easy way to fix this, and it may be impossible.

Ideally you should stop using that machine immediately. At the very least, try not to write anything to the hard drive. The contents of the file you need might still be present on the hard drive in unallocated space. Each new file you or Windows creates might overwrite the data you want.

Check out this page and read the *"The Safest Way to Recover a Deleted File"* or *"The Quicker, Riskier Way to Recover a Deleted File"* section:

https://www.howtogeek.com/169344/how-to-recover-a-deleted-file-the-ultimate-guide/

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, hopefully it wasn't much. If you don't have a backup of your key file or a seed phrase for your accounts, the only thing would be trying data rescue software, maybe you're lucky. There is nothing else you can do, unfortunately. Have a nice day though, and don't forget to backup your wallets next time ! :)